# Does a bijection $f:\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}^2$ have an continuous extension from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}^2$?

Tags: general-topology

> **Question.** Pick out the true statements.
>
> 1. Let $f:\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}^2$ be a bijection. There exists a continuous function from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}^2$ which extends $f$.
> 2. Let $D$ denote the closed unit disc in $\Bbb{R}^2$. There exists a continuous mapping $f:D\setminus \{(0,0)\}\to \{x \in \Bbb{R} \mid |x| \le1\}$ which is onto.
> 3. Let $D$ denote the closed unit disc in $\Bbb{R}^2$. Then there exists a continuous mapping $f:D \setminus \{(0,0)\}\to \{x \in \Bbb{R} \mid |x|>1\}$ which is onto.

**My Attempt.**

1. For this option try to think geometrically but cannot properly figure out such an extension. (I thought this extension as a long curve on $xy$-plane joining each $f(n)$....I actually try to PASTE $\Bbb{R}$ on $\Bbb{R}^2$ like that curve but pasting each $n$ with its image $f(n)$...but it is not so clear enough too.)
2. **True**  (The map $(x,y)\mapsto x$ is such a map.)
3. **False** ($D \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ is connected whereas $\{x \in \Bbb{R} \mid |x|>1\}$ is disconnected.)

Can anyone please help me in the option 1. Thank you.

Comment: 1. Linearly interpolate.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown....well... what is the role of the bijection $f$ in linear interpolation....?

Comment: Absolutely none! Any map $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb R^2$ can be so interpolated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make Lord Shark's comment more explicit define the extension $g$ as

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
a &=& \lfloor x \rfloor \\
g(x)&=& 
f(a)x+(f(a+1)-f(a)) \lbrace x \rbrace 
\end{array}
$$

where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor of $x$ and $\lbrace x \rbrace = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ is the fractional part.

Comment: But $g$ should have $\Bbb{R}$ as domain...!!!

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh It has domain $\mathbb R$ now. Sorry for the confusion in my initial answer.

Comment: ..thanks..I got it.